# Is Lúthien by far the greatest child of Iluvatar who ever lived?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

In the chapter *Of the Flight of the Noldor* in *The Silmarillion*, when Fëanor is leading his host from Aman for to recover the Silmarils from Morgoth, a messenger arrives from Manwë and says, in part:

> The lies of Melkor thou shalt unlearn in bitterness.  Vala he is, thou saist.  Then thou hast sworn in vain, for none of the Valar canst thou overcome now or ever within the halls of Eä, not though Eru who thou namest had made thee thrice greater than thou art.

Much later, in the chapter *Of Beren and Lúthien*, Lúthien puts Morgoth to sleep with her singing, allowing Beren to take one of the Silmarils.  By any reasonable definition, she overcame Morgoth, even if only temporarily.  Does this imply that she's more than three times greater than Fëanor, himself one of the greatest Elves who ever lived?

The answers seems to be a clear "yes," if the messenger from Manwë can be taken as speaking accurately.  Is there any reason not to reach this conclusion?

The only objection I can think of is that Morgoth's personal power decreased over time as he spread it around to corrupt Arda.  But the messenger did say "now or ever," so that seems irrelevant.

Comment: It isn't a contest of strength. Fëanor was the only one who could possibly have unlocked the Silmarils to get the light to restore the Trees; certainly no Vala could do so, and even less so Lúthien. Rock-scissors-paper, but much more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

I fear you are trying to read a bit too much precision into the story.  The statement from Manwë is about taking arms and conquering Morgoth. As predicted, this turned out to be far beyond the capabilities of all the Elves.  In matters of force, Morgoth was far superior to any mortal or group of mortals.

Lúthien did not meet him headlong and batter him unconscious, but lulled him to sleep.  This is not a matter of force vs force at all, and can't be judged on the same scale.  I'd also note, that Lúthien did not defeat Morgoth, but only for a few fleeting moments distracted him enough to allow them to escape Thangorodrim with a single Silmaril.

The two deeds were simply incommensurate.

Comment: I read the context not as conquering Morgoth by force, but as recovering the Silmarils by any means, since that's the point of Fëanor's oath.  Sure, he's leading a great host at the time, and no doubt intends to *try* recovering them by force, but the statement from Manwë's messenger reads more broadly than that to me.  "You're not powerful enough to take the Silmarils from Morgoth, whatever you do."  But Lúthien forced Morgoth into unconsciousness (do the Valar even ordinarily sleep?) in what looks to me like an amazing display of power.  But I suppose my anonymous downvoters disagree.

Comment: You might be right, but that doesn't seem to most obvious reading of the quote. It was made in the context of a proposed armed attack on Morgoth so "overcome" pretty much has to be read in that sense.

Comment: @Sean You're overlooking the fact that Morgoth (effectively, though indirectly by way of Carcharoth) also recovered the Silmaril almost immediately. One could argue that some level of divine intervention led Carcharoth to wander in his madness into Doriath, taking the Silmaril beyond Morgoth's reach for the time being.